# DataContractSerializer does not derserialize custom enum

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, enums, datacontractserializer

I got class serialized with:

```
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(creature));
    var str = new System.IO.FileStream("D://test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    serializer.WriteObject(str, creatures[1]);
    str.Close();
}
```

and deserialize it with

```
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(creature));
    var str = new System.IO.FileStream("D://test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open);                    
    creature t = (creature)serializer.ReadObject(str);
    str.Close();
}
```

and get an exeption

> "XmlException: Type not found; name: stats, namespace: http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"

`stats` is an `enum`, and the `creature` class refers to it.

```
[DataContract]
public enum stats { [EnumMember] STR, [EnumMember] DEX, [EnumMember] CON, [EnumMember] INT, [EnumMember] WIS, [EnumMember] CHA };
```

Does anyone know what can be the problem? (i tried without `[EnumMember]` declaration, same thing).

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Please [edit] your question to share a full [mcve] including the (possibly simplified) `creature` type and a specific instance that generates the exception.

Comment: Incidentally, here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dbc2/59a5a655602e0aad7a246dec8012aefa) of my attempt to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you, i have tried to make cut version of all the classes involved but could not reproduce the problem. I have decided to switch to binary serializer and it works.